# Design Pattern for java threading

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a background service that has a thread running every 15 seconds and doing some work.

```
public class CacheCleaner implements Runnable, BackgroundService {
    ....

    @Override
    public void run() {
      ....
    }
}
```

BackgroundService is another interface that I have defined with methods that I want every background service in the system to implement.

```
public interface BackgroundService
{
   String getName();
   void start(long initialDelay);
   .....
}
```

The problem is that I want to do some work (3-4 lines of basic code) in the run method of every such class (there are 10-15 of them). Is there a design pattern or any better way I can achieve this rather than copy pasting the 4 lines in each of the 15 run methods?

NOTE: I mention the run() method since I only want those 4 lines of code to be executed when the thread is active.

Comment: Make `BackgroundService` implement `Runnable` with `run` defined?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of what you want? If you have an abstract class with a run method, then extend that, you can call `super.run()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inheritance ... for example,

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseRunnable implements Runnable {
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ... // base work here!
    }
}

public class CacheCleaner extends AbstractBaseRunnable implements BackgroundService {
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        ... // particular work for CacheCleaner here!!
    }
}
```

Comment: ah. Same idea here, but I was too slow ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something similar to this.

```
public abstract class Task implements Runnable {

 @Override
 void run() {
  //do ur common stuff here (3-4 lines of code that u mentioned)
  execute();
 }
 public abstract void execute();

}
```

You implement the Runnable/Callable whichever you like/need. In above code "Task" class implements the Runnable and also implements the "run()" method. Here in "run()" method you can do whatever common stuff you want to do and declare a abstract method "execute()" which can be implemented by the implementation classes based on the need. Your "CacheCleaner" will look like this:

```
public class CacheCleaner extends Task implements BackgroundService {
 ....

 @Override
 public void execute() {
  ....
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an abstract class containing your 3-4 lines of basic code and every of you 10-15 background services subclassing it.

```
public abstract class AbstractBackgroundService implements Runnable,BackgroundService{

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        prepareRun();

        runImpl(); 
    }

    private void prepareRun() {
        // your 3-4 lines basic code
    }

    protected abstract void runImpl();
}
```